# Select element by ID and CSS attribute

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

Through CSS I set all divs to `visibility :hidden`. By clicking the item in the navbar I want the target div to be set to `visibility :visible`. This works just fine but I want to avoid setting it again if it is already visible.

This code doesn't work

```
function showNewElement(actID) {
   ID = actID.substring(1, actID.length);
   $('.mainDiv:visible').css("visibility", "hidden");
   $("#" + ID + ':hidden').css("visibility", "visible").hide().fadeIn('fast');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dEnx5/

So I had to wrap it in an if-Statement

```
function showNewElement(actID) {
    var ID = actID.substring(1, actID.length);
    if ($("#" + ID).css("visibility") != "visible") {
        $('.mainDiv').css("visibility", "hidden");
        $("#" + ID).css("visibility", "visible").hide().fadeIn('fast');
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qUe6k/4/

Why does it not work the other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [jQuery - :visible Selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

> Elements are considered visible if they consume space in the document.
>   Elements with visibility: hidden or opacity: 0 are considered visible, since they still consume space in the layout.

So, although you cannot see the elements, they are not in the `:visible` set.

What you can do instead, is using `display: none` on the `mainDiv` elements. Then it will be considered invisible

```css
.mainDiv {
    display: none;
}
```

and then change the jQuery to just

```js
function showNewElement(actID) {
    ID = actID.substring(1, actID.length);
    $('.mainDiv:visible').hide();
    $("#" + ID + ':hidden').fadeIn();
}
```

See modified [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dEnx5/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Write:

```
function showNewElement(actID) {
    ID = actID.substring(1, actID.length);
    if ($("#" + ID).css("visibility") == "hidden"){
        $(".mainDiv:visible").css("visibility", "hidden");
        $("#" + ID).css("visibility", "visible");
    }
}
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/qUe6k/5/)

Comment: I actually wanted to get the 2-liner to work because logically it seems right but it doesn't work. I want to understand why ;)

Answer (score 0):

It works if you change:

```
$("#" + ID + ':hidden').css("visibility", "visible").hide().fadeIn('fast');
```

To:

```
$("#" + ID).css("visibility", "visible").hide().fadeIn('fast');
```